# How to fill svg shape when i touch on svg image without loss quality of svg

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, androidsvg

This image is SVG image which is loaded into SVGImageView. I can't fill color into SVG with onTouch listener. I am tired to fill color into particular shape or area. Help me. Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/96TM5.png

And fill area with different color like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9zXG.jpg

Comment: How are you displaying the SVG? Are you using a WebView, or one of the SVG libraries for Android?  Please provide more details.

Comment: SVG libraries to load svg using this 
 lib : https://github.com/senkir/androidsvg/tree/master/src/com/caverock/androidsvg

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK at the moment none of the SVG libraries for Android support interaction.  I am the author of AndroidSVG and it is a high priority on my list of things to implement.

If you need it now, however, I think you will need to resort to displaying the SVG in a [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and using Javascript events to determine what is clicked on.

Comment: paul sir, thank u for help me. But is it posible to fill color with particular area in svg using WebView in android.

Comment: Yes. You would do it the same as you would in a browser, since that is what `WebView` is.

Comment: thank u so much for giving me this solution . i will try. thank u once again.